# Corda Enterprise generates a details-node-.log file

Tags: corda

at the beginning of the project we worked with Corda Opensource, and we used the command line argument logging-level=WARN to change the log level of the nodes.
When we started using Corda Enterprise, we noticed that a **details-node-.log** file was created. It is a log file that grows fast and is at TRACE level.
Our question: can the log in this file affect the performance of our cordapps and can we change the level of this log or disable it?

Comment: [This page](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.5/node/operating/monitoring-logging.html) has some tips on how to configure the logging level; hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corda Enterprise adds that logger which is not present in Open Source Corda.

The only impact I can see for a CordApp could be probably the lack of space on the server, so if in your case this log file becomes too big too quickly, it would be a good idea to configure it to avoid possible problems.

You can override the log4j configuration file and give it as input to the jar like this:

`java -jar Dlog4j.configurationFile=new-log-config.xml <en-service>.jar`

It is standard log4j, so you can also configure the rollover period and the size.
For reference, you can also take a look to [this](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release/os/4.6/config/dev/log4j2.xml) log4j.xml in open source Corda to see how the loggers are configured.

So, can probably override the logger you're concerned about with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Properties>
    ...
    <Property name="detailLogLevel">TRACE</Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    ...
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="Detailed-RollingFile-Appender"
                fileName="${log-path}/details-${log-name}.log"
                filePattern="${archive}/details-${log-name}.%date{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">

        <Policies>
            ...your policies...
        </Policies>

        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
            ...your strategy...
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>

    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    ...
    <Logger name="DetailedInfo" additivity="false" level="${detailLogLevel}">
        <AppenderRef ref="Detailed-RollingFile-Appender"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the level by setting this system property in your start script:

```
-DdetailLogLevel=info
```